# Thymeleaf + HTML5 - can't find JS or CSS

Tags: javascript, css, spring, html, thymeleaf

I'm working on a new application using Thymeleaf that's built upon another one. But instead of fast forwarding the development, I'm stuck on a issue for the better part of the night.

The thing is, Eclipse says (on its console) Thymleaf has been loaded upon accessing the application. So far so good! But I lack all CSS and JS. My landing page has a link to the following but not fancy `login.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:include="fragments/login :: loginFragment">
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="login-container animated fadeInDown">
    <div class="loginbox bg-white">
        <form th:action="@{/login}" method="post">

            <div class="loginbox-title"><span style="text-transform: uppercase;" th:text="#{gen.signin}"></span></div>

            <div class="loginbox-textbox">
                <input type="text" id="ssoId" name="ssoId" class="form-control" th:placeholder="#{gen.username}" />
            </div>
            <div class="loginbox-textbox">
                <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="form-control" th:placeholder="#{gen.passwd}" />
            </div>
<!--            <div class="loginbox-forgot"> -->
<!--                <a href="#" th:href="@{/forgotPassword}" th:text="#{gen.lostPasswd}">Forgot Password?</a> -->
<!--            </div> -->
            <div class="loginbox-submit">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" th:value="#{gen.signin}"/>
            </div>

            <div style="text-align: center;" ><span th:text="#{gen.appVersion}"></span></div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#ssoId').focus();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It refers to loginFragment defined as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:id="loginFragment" th:fragment="loginFragment">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

    <link rel="icon" href="assets/img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon" />

    <link th:href="@{/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css}" />
    <link th:href="@{/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css}"/>
    <link th:href="@{/assets/css/beyond-login.css}"/>
    <link th:href="@{/assets/css/demo.min.css}" />
    <link th:href="@{/assets/css/animate.min.css}" />
    <link th:href="@{/assets/css/jquery-ui.css}" />

    <link th:href="@{/assets/css/login.css}"/>

    <link th:href="@{http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,400,600,700,300}"/>

    <script th:src="@{/assets/js/skins.min.js}" ></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/js/jquery-2.2.3.min.js}" ></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js}" ></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/js/slimscroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js}" ></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/js/beyond.js}" ></script>
    <script th:src="@{/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js}" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the `webapp` folder structure is:

```
webapp
    assets
        css
        img
        js
    WEB-INF
        html
            admin
            fragments
            home
            login.html
```

The landing page uses a different fragment to load CSS and JS, but neither fragments can't read the CSS and JS files. I've tried comparing with the other project to no evident difference. Even file permissions are the same.

On the landing page, Firebug shows me this:

```
<script src="/cms-stock/assets/js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"> 
    Reload the page to get source for: http://localhost:8080/cms-stock/assets/js/jquery-ui.js
</script>
```

And everytime I try to call a CSS or JS file on the browser, I am redirected to the landing page.

What am I missing here?

Comment: try renaming the folder "assets" to -static- and folder "html" to -templates-

Comment: Still no luck... This is driving me mad...

Comment: There is a well explained doc over css, JS ect resources with thymeleaf. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/pdf/spring-boot-reference.pdf   page 79.

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte, I'm not using Spring Boot. Thanks for the input, though!

Comment: Did you find the solution? Im facing same problem...

Answer (score 0):

By default, Thymeleaf expects us to place templates in the `src/main/resources/templates` folder.

And for CSS and JavaScript files, the default directory is `src/main/resources/static`.

Change your `resources` folder structure to:

```
src
   main
      resources
         static
            css
            img
            js
         templates
            admin
            fragments
            home
            login.html
```

CSS usage e.g.

```
<link th:href="@{/css/beyond-login.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

JS usage e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/beyond.js}"></script>
```