# Thymeleaf 3 + Spring 4 - Exception processing template, what's going on?

Tags: java, html, css, spring, thymeleaf

I'm working on a new app using Spring 4 and Thymeleaf 3.

My `LoginController.java` has the following mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/home", "/welcome" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index(Principal principal) {

    //logs debug message
    if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
        logger.debug("getWelcome is executed!");
    }
    return principal != null ? "home/homeSignedIn" : "home/homeNotSignedIn";
}
```

So, when I access the app, without being logged in the called page is `home/homeNotSignedIn.html`, which is posted bellow.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
      xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" 
      layout:decorate="fragments/app">

<head>
    <title th:text="#{view.index.title}">Welcome!</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div layout:fragment="content">
        <div class="container2">
            <th:block th:if="${message != null}">
                <div th:replace="fragments/alert :: alertFragment (type=${#strings.toLowerCase(message.type)}, message=${message.message})">&nbsp;</div>
            </th:block>
            <p />
            <p />
              <a href="/login" th:href="@{/login}" class="btn btn-large btn-success">Sign up</a>
            <p />
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This page has a direct reference to a file called `app.html` which contains the layout for the application, seen bellow.

I'm having basically two problems.

1) Thymeleaf cries about this:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcher] in context with path [/cms-stock] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/templates/home/homeNotSignedIn.html]")] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: layout:decorate/data-layout-decorate must appear in the root element of your template
```

2) Maybe related to 1), I get no CSS or JS loaded.

I have started this app as Spring-boot and, probably very stupid of me, I could't get it running. Then, adapted a working `pom.xml` from another app, and got the problem number 2, further described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218626/thymeleaf-html5-cant-find-js-or-css?noredirect=1#comment65779863_39218626).

I'm at a loss here. Please advise!

Comment: where in your app are the css and js resources? have you configured Spring boot to find these resources?

Comment: I'm not using Spring boot, because I couldn't get it running. CSS and JS are located and specified at `src/main/webapp/static`.

Comment: hi, where'd you find `layout:decorate` attribute? I was trying to read about this but couldn't find anything.